# Irregularities when csv loaded in power query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I performed data cleaning using pandas and created a csv file. When I loaded the file in power query, I saw there were null values in few columns. I am sure that all null values were removed when performing cleaning task. I even re verified it.

UPDATE:- Instead of csv file, I tried creating an excel file and when I loaded it there were no null values.

Can anybody point out what's the issue with csv file method?

Comment: In Power Query (in the editor), *null* means the cell (or csv field) is completely empty.  What do you expect to be in that field?  I don't know what it means in your data source, or what you removed. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Typically associated with the format of the CSV. Such as single quotes inside text fields also using single quotes to start and stop the text field.